# UWP GridView .xml data binding [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, uwp-xaml

Dear all I am struggling to bind my .xml data to GridView in my UWP project. I could not find any example how to bind .xml data to GridView. Could you please help me giving a sample code which shows how to bind .xml data UWP GridView. Please note that my .xml data is very large (5000 rows).
Thank you very much.

Comment: Firstly, if you have lots of data, I would suggest you to save the data into a database then you can access part of the data conveniently. Do you must have the requirement to save the data into a .xml file? Maybe you need to deserialize to an object then bind to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think database cannot be used in UWP. Thus I use XML data. if you know how to use database please let me know about it, with some example. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can try to choose SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, database can be used in UWP apps. If your UWP app target on version 16299 and later, you can use both SQLite and SQL Server database base on your selection. If your app need to be compatible with previous version, you can only use the SQLite database, since SQL Server database begin to support on version 16299.

There are many info on the internet to introduce to use SQLite and SQL Server database, but they are all using C#, it would be similar on VB project.

Here are the introduction using SQLite database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/#YGMf6G0GsZzBG4YG.97

Here is the detailed introduction using SQL Server database:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases